# Fetch Multiple Records from Mysql Database Using Where Clause

Tags: mysql, jsp, jdbc

Im using a web application ,which runs on Apache Tomcat and has Mysql Database as backend

I want to retrieve multiple rows for a particular column usin the Where clause

For Example If I give select * from xyz where type=abc

I should get all the rows having type abc.

Problem:

I use the JDBC connection to achieve this, however Only the 1st row matching the where condition is returned rather than all the rows (even though multiple rows match the criteria in database)

Kindly help me resolve this

Code:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<html>
<head><link href="style.css" rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head>

<body bgcolor="white" >

<div id="container">
<div id="header">
    <img src="logo.jpg">

  <div class ="horiztext"><p> Order Tracker</p></div>
  </div>

</div>
  <br>

    <img src="banner.jpg" width="1500 " height="5"><br>
    <% if(session.getAttribute("username") !=null)
{
 %>
     <div id="navbar">
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="newoder.jsp">New Order</a></li> 
        <li><a href="updateorder.jsp">Update Order</a></li> 
        <li><a href="trackorder.jsp">Track Order</a></li> 
        <li><a href="trackdelay.jsp">Track Delay</a></li> 
        <li><a href="vieworder.jsp">View Database</a></li> 
        <li><a href="delete.jsp">Delete Order</a></li> 
        <li><a href="logout.jsp">Logout</a></li>
  </ul> 
  </div>   
  <br>
  <br>

    <form>
    <TABLE cellpadding="15" border="1" style="background-color: #ffffcc;">
    <%
    String ProductNamez=request.getParameter("ProductName");

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307
 /test","root", "root");
    Statement st=conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE ProductName = '"+
  ProductNamez +"' ");
    if(rs.next()){ 
        %>

<tr>
<tr><th>Serial No</th>
<th>Product Name</th>
<th>Product Type</th>
<th>Model</th>
<th>Make</th>
<th>License / Voucher</th>
<th>Location</th>



</tr> 
<tr>
<td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(5)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(6)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(7)%></td>


</tr>
          <%
    }
    %>
    </table>
    </form>
    <%
} 
else { %>
you are not logged in click here to <a href="eric.jsp"><b>login</b></a>

<%
} %> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll be wanting

```
    while (rs.next()){
```

instead of

```
    if (rs.next()){
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you just do a `if(rs.next()){` so only the first row is shown.

You should do this instead

```
while (rs.next()) {

        [...]

    }
```